# How can I get the default title text style in android

Tags: android, user-interface, styles

I'm writing an android application and want to get a default look & feel for my menus.
I want to imitate the look & feel of the setting menu.

On an android device, hit Settings->Sound.
In this menu, I want to get the style of the title. (the one that's named "Sound"). The sub-titles ("General", "Incoming Calls", etc.) are in listSeparatorTextViewStyle.

Is there a built-in name for the title style as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can see here in this, they have added preferenceScreen, which will be whole screen,

Preference category will be the tiltle(like General,incoming etc)
and inside this tag you can use other preferance as mentioned in the example.

```
 <PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/sound_settings" android:key="sound_settings">    
 <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/sound_category_sound_title"/>
   <CheckBoxPreference android:key="silent" android:title="@string/silent_mode_title" android:summary="@string/silent_mode_summary" android:persistent="false" android:disableDependentsState="true"/>
 <ListPreference android:key="vibrate" android:title="@string/vibrate_title" android:summary="@string/vibrate_summary" android:entries="@array/vibrate_entries" android:entryValues="@array/vibrate_values"/><com.android.settings.RingerVolumePreference android:key="ring_volume" android:dependency="silent" android:title="@string/all_volume_title" android:summary="@string/ring_volume_summary" android:dialogTitle="@string/all_volume_title" android:persistent="false" android:streamType="ring"/>
 <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/sound_category_calls_title"/><com.android.settings.DefaultRingtonePreference android:key="ringtone" android:title="@string/ringtone_title" android:summary="@string/ringtone_summary" android:dialogTitle="@string/ringtone_title" android:persistent="false" android:ringtoneType="ringtone"/>
  <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/sound_category_notification_title"/><!-- Do not nest these, or removals in code will break --><com.android.settings.DefaultRingtonePreference android:key="notification_sound" android:title="@string/notification_sound_title" android:summary="@string/notification_sound_summary" android:dialogTitle="@string/notification_sound_dialog_title" android:persistent="false" android:ringtoneType="notification"/>
 <CheckBoxPreference android:key="notification_pulse" android:title="@string/notification_pulse_title" android:summary="@string/notification_pulse_summary" android:persistent="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this screen does not contains `Menu` or `Menuitems` . its a header separated ListView ,where header's are disabled .
so basically to achieve this you can create an activity which contains menu options .
 in case there are sub menus also , use expandable listview instead .

many example exist , so search for it .